# Use Access Point to extend network to remote computer without a wireless card

Tags: networking, wifi, access-point, wireless-bridge

I am trying to set up a computer on a rolling cart so it can be move around the office to be wireless without actually having a wireless card in it. So I need to go from NIC to ethernet cable to wireless but have it so no network settings need to be changed on the computer itself.

Caveats:
1) Its a government owned computer that I can't make changes to or add hardware.
2) Can't install USB wifi dongle because of #1

I have a Dlink DAP 2360 that I am trying to set up but can't seem to get to work. They have options for AP, WDS with AP, WDS and Wireless client.

I have tried everything I can think of to get it so I can attach the computer to the Dlink and have the wireless connect to my main router so the rolling computer acts as if it is just on the routers network.

Tried using the routers settings in the WLAN side.
Tried setting the LAN side to use the main router as the default gateway.
Tried using WDS, WDS with AP and Wireless Client options.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can purchase a range extender and connect to one of the ethernet ports on it.  The range extender would connect to your wireless network.  Range extenders are physically small and affordable by most.

You should ensure that the government computer is authorized to be on a wireless network first.

Comment: +1 for the second paragraph. The OP may be in for a world of pain otherwise.

Comment: The computers are allowed to be on wifi as long as they are secured via WPA2 (not WEP).

Answer (score 2):

You should use an acccess point to act as a wireless client. It connects to the wireless network and via cable to the laptop. I used to have an old dlink dap to do this and I think you can do the same with the 2360. Configure it as wireless client as if it was a computer, it will take an ip and connect the laptop

Comment: I did try setting it up as a wireless client. Gave it the SSID of the wireless network but the computer that I am accessing the Dlink from only ever gets to the AP it wont get an actual internet connection.

Under the LAN settings I have tried DHCP and Static. The DHCP option doesnt seem to work and the static option I have tried setting it to both the default (192.168.0.x) and giving it the routers IP (192.168.10.1) and an IP on the 192.168.10.x network.

Comment: I have no idea what's wrong, but I can verify this approach does work.